# Loop only if condition is met?

Tags: php

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
if ($boolean == true) {
    foreach ($variables as $variable) {
}

// some code that can be run either with a loop or without

if ($boolean == true) {
    } // end the foreach loop
}
```

Or is there another way to do this without rewriting the same code twice just to satisfy all possibilities?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense

Comment: @JohnConde It's pseudo code, of course it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain it more precisely?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a while loop.

Comment: The concept doesn't make any sense. Real code or not.

Comment: Pseudocode should make logical sense.

Comment: Loops and conditionals have to be nested properly, they can't overlap partially.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of how you intend to use this?

Comment: I don't think your pseudocode is really illustrating what you're going for. Maybe try editing the question to add more of a description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Dionne Warwick voice) That's what functions are for:

```
function doSomething() {
    //whatever
};

if ($boolean) 
    for($variables as $variable) doSomething();
else 
    doSomething();
```

That kind of syntax you thought about isn't valid in PHP. It's a very clever idea though. But code maintenance of one of there would bring hell on earth. Better forget it.

Answer (score 4):

The conventional way is to *always* use a loop.  If there is only one item, then you can still loop just *once*.

**Contrived example**

```
$values = …;
if (!is_array($values)) {
    $values = array($values);
}

foreach ($values as $value) {
    // Do your work
}
```

Comment: An array cast in the `foreach` loop  would make the `is_array` check redundant. i.e. _`foreach((array) $values as ...`_

Comment: In most cases, the net result will be the same; but not all, hence the explicit check (principle of least surprise and all that).

Comment: thanks for the clarification - i will remenber that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're asking, but if you want to run a loop at least once, and continue looping for a condition then "Do While" is your answer.  A do while works just like a while, but checks AFTER the first loop is run - meaning it always runs at least once.

[PHP Docs for Do While](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

> Do-while loops are very similar to while loops, except the truth expression is checked at the end of each iteration instead of in the beginning.

Example:

```
$arrayofstuff = array('one ','two ','three '); // Optional array of stuff
$i=0; // Counts the loops
echo 'starting...';
do {
    // Do stuff at least once here

    // Array stuff if needed
    if(isset($arrayofstuff[$i])) {
        echo $arrayofstuff[$i]; // Uses loop # to get from array
    } else {
        break; // ends loop because array is empty
    }
    $i++;
} while (true);
```

For what it's worth, forcing a variable into a single value array would probably be easier to read.  As you can see there's a lot going on here for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

why not just plain:

```
if($boolean){
   foreach($a as $b){   
     // do stuff
   } 
}else{
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want would be done like so...

```
foreach ($variables as $variable) {

    // some code that can be run either with a loop or without

    if ($boolean !== true) {
        break;
    }

}
```

But this is not as readable as just using an if/else statement